# getting an expired ssl certificate when browsing using a different IP

Tags: ip, ssl, certificate

Recently my office having an issue on remotes site,
their ip are getting an expired ssl certificates when browsing this website
`help.cambridgeinternational.org`.

If your are successful to browse to this website, the certificates show be like this:
[image: normal ssl certificate]

When remote site try to access to this website, it will show

> "This site can’t provide a secure connectionhelp.cambridgeinternational.org uses an unsupported protocol.
> ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH"

I use firefox to browse this website it will show: "403 forbidden"
and what's in the certificate , is an expired SSL.
[image: Expired ssl certificate]

What could be wrong that make all that ip showing different things? is ISP the root cause?

Tested using google dns and still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

> I use firefox to browse this website it will show :"403 forbidden" and what's in the certificate , is an expired ssl . Expired ssl certificate

This (CN = ssl1044664.cloudflaressl.com) is the certificate which is served when [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) is not used by the client. But all modern browsers use SNI, so this cannot be the fault of Firefox. This looks more like something fiddling with the traffic in a broken way, like some misconfigured corporate proxy/firewall or DPI capable router.